# How to encode initializer in gnosis-safe proxy contract?

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, gnosis-safe, gnosis

Currently I start learning gnosis-safe contracts I have a small doubt in gnosis-proxy contract how to encode initializer in createProxyWithNonce function.

Reference transaction id : https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x1a06fa9fa2e420391ceb159ea41eeb595750ed0d88a14be2e154a7df959f46bc

Answer (score 3):

As proxies canot use the conventional constructor approach, the common way to compensate for this is to provide an initialization function (see [OpenZepplin](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/proxies#the-constructor-caveat)).

To avoid that this can be front-run in a malicious way the Safe proxy factory allows you to specify the initializer and will then also invoke this initializer after the proxy has been deployed.

Therefore the initializer is just the encoded method call to the initializer method (the `setup` method in case of the Safe contract).

You can find an example for this in the [Safe contracts tests](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/test/factory/ProxyFactory.spec.ts#L85).

Comment: Thanks @Richard. I am stuck with the same problem. It is clear to me that the proxies are initialized as usual via an initializing function call that acts like a constructor. However the question remains what is the encoding. Usually for the on-chain encoding I would use `abi.encodeWithSignature("setup()", arg1, arg2, ...., argn)`. From inspection I figured that the last arg is just the encoding of the array of signers. But it is not clear to me what comes before that.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/gnosis/safe-factories/blob/master/contracts/Safe_1_1_1_Factory.sol#L28 can give you some pointers